# Are these UML diagrams correct?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

Are these diagrams correct? I am talking just about UML specifications. The first one is a class diagram of a code implementation. The second one is an activity diagram showing how to repair some 3D models.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagrams look good, although there are a few minor errors:

1. `GameObject` is used as a type, but not defined. You will have to define it as a class, an interface or a data type.
2. `List<...>` is not correct. In UML, use the multiplicity `*`, as follows: `- NPCs : GameObject[*]`
3. In the activity diagram, the labels along flows leaving a decision should be between square brackets, e.g. `[yes]` and `[no]`.
4. There is a merge symbol missing before `search for holes`. If an action has two incoming flows, this means that the action is executed after *all* incoming flows have been followed, but in your case, you want the action to be executed after *one of* the three flows has been followed.

One final remark: you didn't specify any multiplicities for the association between `Character_Controller` and `Teleporter`. This is okay, but it means that the multiplicities are undefined, i.e. it is not specified to how many instances of Teleporter a Character_Controller is associated and it is not specified to how many instances of Character_Controller a Teleporter is associated. Since you did specify multiplicities for the aggregations, I would advise to specify multiplicities here as well.